# (How) Can I rapidly generate undeclared boilerplate in IntelliJ using the quick-fix feature?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA supports a quick-fix through static analysis, by default bound to Alt+Enter when the cursor is on an error marker, for example, an undeclared local may be declared with the correct type based on context.

Coming from Eclipse, a common usage scenario for me is to type out a line of Java with one or more undeclared *things* (locals, methods, types, etc.) and generate each of them in turn via quick-fix. This allows me to implement features top-down and defer those pesky distracting details until they become relevant.

I can still do this in IntelliJ, but it's a more involved task because:

- The cursor must be moved to the error marker itself. The whole line is not scanned automatically.
- The cursor is not *returned* to its previous location after the code is generated, but rather is left on the new boilerplate.

Can I configure the IDE to support these two "features" or can I accomplish this use case in some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem, you can use F2 to move to the next highlighted error.

For the second one, IntelliJ IDEA assumes that you're actually going to write the implementation of the element after you create it from usage, so it does not return the caret to the position where the quickfix was invoked. However, you can use "Navigate | Last Edit Location" (Ctrl-Shift-Backspace in the default keymap) to go back to the place where you invoked the quickfix.